# How to get the Viewing Direction in the fragment shader while rendering a Fullscreen Quad

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I have to render a scene in 2 steps. First I render into a Frame Buffer Object and I reuse the texture of the FBO for the next step. I render the texture on a fullscreen quad like this with a shader attached:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,-10.0, 0.0,1.0,0.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0,-1.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0,-1.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0,0.0);
   glEnd();

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPopMatrix();
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glPopMatrix();
```

In the attached Fragment Shader I need the viewing direction to the actual fragment of the old scene in Eye Space Coords. My first idea was like this:

```
vec2 uv = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
vec3 viewDirEye = normalize(vec3(uv.x*2.0-1.0, (uv.y)*2.0-1.0, -1.0));
```

But it seems not working, and I don't know why. It would be great if someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula does set up a direction vector from the texture coordinates in *normalized device coordinates*, but not in *eye space*.

You have to take the projection matrix into account (which will define the horizontal and vertical field of view angle).
You can use the *inverse* projection matrix to transform into eye space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But which Projection Matrix should I use? The one from the first render step or the other one from the Orthogonal Projection of the second render step?

Comment: Since I assume you want to restore the eye space positions used in the first pass, you should of course use the corresponding matrix. Using it on an orthogonal projection matrix would also be quite useless, since the viewing direction would be identical for every point, then.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect! I love you guy! If anyone else has a problem with getting the projection matrix with derefered shading I recommend this link: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space